# Google is indexing my website's pages slowly, what is the problem?

Tags: google-index

How long will it take for Google to index whole pages, is it normal to take more than 2 months to index 75K out of 3.2M pages?
I added sitemap to google and set robot.txt more than 2 months ago, in this period Google bots indexed only 75 thousand pages out of 3.2 million, is it normal?

If there is a problem, how could I understand?

[image: Google is indexing slowly, what is the problem]